# Function $ f $ defined on unit disk $ D $ has real values on $ \partial D $, why is $ f $ real valued?

Tags: complex-analysis

I have a function $ f $ that is analytic on the unit disc and real valued on the unit circle. I want to prove that $ f $ is real valued on the unit disk.

I know that I need to use the identity theorem, but I am unsure how. The only thing I can think to do is:

Let $ g $ be some real valued function s.t. $ g(e^{i\theta}) = f(e^{i\theta}) $ then $  f = g $, but this argument obviously isn't sound. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If $f$ is analytic and real valued on any open subset of the complex plane, it is constant on that subset.  You can prove this using the Cauchy-Riemann equations.  I don't know if this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: this answers a different question (assuming $f$ is holomorphic).  I leave it here for now because it may have some value anyway.

I assume that $f$ is continuous on the closed disc.  One approach uses Schwarz' reflection principle: The function $f$ can be extended to an entire function by defining

$$ f(z) = \overline{f(1/\overline{z})} $$

for $|z| > 1$.  (The hardish part of the reflection principle is that the resulting function is indeed holomorphic also for points on the unit circle.)  Now $f$ is extended to a bounded entire function (since it is bounded on the compact closed unit disc) so it must be constant.

Another approach uses the open mapping theorem.  Suppose $f$ is not constant.  Then the image of the open unit disc is open and bounded (since $f$ is continuous on the closed unit disc).  In particular it must have a non-real boundary point.  This boundary point must be attained by $f$ on the compact closed unit disc.  But $f$ is an open mapping on the open unit disc so this non-real boundary point must be attained on the unit circle.  Contradiction.

Comment: Given that it's tagged complex analysis, I would bet that analytic is for complex analytic=holomorphic.

Comment: Schwartz principle is $f(z) = \overline{f(\overline{z})}$ so it doesn't help at all. Moreover the above proof implies that any holomorphic function that is bounded on $\mathbb{D}$ is actually bounded on $\mathbb{C}$ and that is false, take for instance $f(z) = z$, which is bounded in $\mathbb{D}$ by $\mathbb{D}$ itself!

Comment: @rewritten You may want to read my answer carefully again and see where it uses the given premises.  Then try it on $f(z)=z$ and see why it does not work in that case.

Answer (score 1):

By analytic on the unit disk, I assume you mean holomorphic on a neighborhood of the closed unit disk. If it's just analytic on the open unit disk, the statement is obviously false, as $f(z)=z $ for $|z|<1$ and $f(z)=0$ for $|z|=1$ is a counterexample.

Recall that the real and imaginary parts of a holomorphic function are harmonic.

The function $\mbox{Im} f$ is harmonic on the unit disk and zero on the unit circle. By the [maximum/minimum principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_principle) for harmonic functions, it follows that $\mbox{Im} f=0$ on the whole unit disk.